# Integer valued signature of $4n$ dimensional orbifolds

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, orbifolds

Let $M^{4n}$ be a smooth oriented $4n$-dimensional manifold without boundary. Then we have an intersection form in $H^{2n}(M^{4n},\mathbb R)$ and such a form has signature $(n_+, n_-)$.

**Question.** I would like to know if this situation generalizes to oriented $4n$-dimensional orbifolds $\widetilde M^{4n}$ without boundary. Namely, that we have a (canonical) well defined intersection form on  $H^{2n}(\widetilde M^{4n},\mathbb R)$ and consequently we can speak of its signature $(n_+, n_-)$? If yes, I would like to have a reference for this statement.

**Remark.** Sometimes signature  on a manifold $M^{4n}$ means $n_+-n_-$. This quantity has a generalization to *obrifolds signature* but it is usually just a rational (non-integer) number. I want it to be integer on the contrary.